# Подсчет строк в datatable с условием

Tags: c#, linq

Есть datatable, в нем несколько колонок. Одна из них "Flag". Как с помощью методов расширения получить количество строк, где "Flag" = true? Что-то вроде этого:

```
var rez = dt_folders.Select().Count(s => s["Flag"] = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt_folders.AsEnumerable().Count(x=>(bool)x["Flag"]);
```

или

```
dt_folders.AsEnumerable().Count(x=>x.Field<bool>("Flag"));
```

или

```
dt_folders.Rows.Count(x=>x.Field<bool>("Flag"));
```